# Kendo UI Html Grid 'an item with the same key has already been added'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using Telerik's Kendo UI, Kendo.Mvc version 2016.3.1028.545

I have a view that contains an html grid like so:

```
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TfUserLoginHistoryReturnModel>()
                .Name("loginHistoryGrid")
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Read(read => read.Action("LoginHistory_Read", "Administration", new { DateStart = Model.StartDate }))
                    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.UserID)
                    )
                )
                .Events(events => events.DataBound("onGridDataBound"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.FullName).Title("Full Name");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Email);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyName).Title("Company");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.UserType).Title("User Type");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.AcceptedTermsDate).Title("Date Accepted Terms").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(125);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.LastSuccessfulLogin).Title("Last Login").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(125);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.NumLogins).Title("Number of Logins");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.TotalTime).Title("Time Logged (minutes)");
                })
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable()
                .Scrollable()
                .Filterable(f => f.Extra(true)
                    .Operators(o => o.ForString(s => s.Clear()
                    .Contains("Contains")
                    .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
                    .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                    .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                    .StartsWith("Starts with")
                    .EndsWith("Ends with")
                    .IsEmpty("Is empty")
                    .IsNotEmpty("Is not empty")
                    .IsNull("Is null")
                    .IsNotNull("Is not null "))))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:500px;" })
            )
```

Associated Scripts:

```
    function onGridDataBound(e) {
        var grid = e.sender;
        if (grid.dataSource.total() == 0) {
            $(grid).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(grid).show();
        }
    }

    function searchUserGrid(e) {
        if ($("#userSearchText").val() == "") {
            $("#loginHistoryGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({ field: "UserId", operator: "equals", value: -1 });
        } else {
            $filter = [{
                "logic": "or",
                "filters": [
                        { field: "FullName", operator: "contains", value: $("#userSearchText").val() },
                        { field: "Email", operator: "contains", value: $("#userSearchText").val() },
                        { field: "CompanyName", operator: "contains", value: $("#userSearchText").val() }
                ]
            }];
            $("#loginHistoryGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter($filter);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Get for that view in the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UsageReport(string DateStart)
    {
        try
        {
            UserLoginHistoryViewModel m = new UserLoginHistoryViewModel();

            //default is yesterday
            DateTime sdt = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DateStart))
            {
                DateTime.TryParse(DateStart, out sdt);
            }
            m.StartDate = sdt;

            return View(m);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("UsageReportGet", ex);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administration");
        }
    }
```

When I run this with a breakpoint and go to that page, it doesn't even hit `LoginHistory_Read` in the controller.  While hitting the grid, it errors out.  Here is the error and stack trace:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147024809   Message=An item with the same key has already
>   been added.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
>          at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
>          at System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary.Add(String key, Object value)
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridBoundColumn'2.CreateHeaderBuilderCore()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridColumnBase'1.CreateHeaderBuilder()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridCellBuilderFactory.CreateHeaderCellBuilder(IGridColumn
>   column)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator'2.MoveNext()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridRowBuilder.CreateRow()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridHeaderRowBuilder.CreateRow()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridRowBuilderDecoratorBase.CreateRow()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridRowBuilderDecoratorBase.CreateRow()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridRowBuilderDecoratorBase.CreateRow()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridRowBuilderDecoratorBase.CreateRow()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridRowBuilderDecoratorBase.CreateRow()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridRowBuilderDecoratorBase.CreateRow()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridRowBuilderDecoratorBase.CreateRow()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridDataSectionBuilder.CreateHeader(GridRenderingData
>   data)
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridScrollingHtmlBuilder.CreateHeader(GridRenderingData
>   renderingData)
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridScrollingHtmlBuilder.AppendData(IHtmlNode div,
>   GridRenderingData renderingData)
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html.GridHtmlBuilder.CreateGrid(IDictionary'2 htmlAttributes, GridFunctionalData functionalData, GridRenderingData
>   renderingData)
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Grid'1.WriteHtml(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.WidgetBase.ToHtmlString()
>          at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase'2.ToHtmlString()
>          at System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Object value)
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(Object value)
>          at ASP._Page_Views_Administration_UsageReport_cshtml.Execute() in
>   C:\Users\tsimpson\Source\Workspaces\CustomerPortal\CEConnect\CEConnect\Views\Administration\UsageReport.cshtml:line
>   42
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList'1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList'1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>   InnerException:

So if I run it without breakpoints, the page will load, but the grid is empty.

I have no idea how to know what it is trying to add to the dictionary at that point.  I compared this to other grids in my site that do work, and don't see what it could be that's causing this issue.

This is a video I made of what walking through it looks like so you can see exactly at which point the error comes up - hopefully that helps.  Be sure to set it to 1080p!  [Kendo Grid Error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEseAkDoh-g)

Let me know what other information is needed to try and determine what it could be.  Thank you!

Comment: Is it loading fine for first time?

Comment: @AkashKC - No.  If I run it without breakpoints, the page will load, but because the grid errors before hitting the Read function there's nothing in it.

Comment: Could you please share your controller implementation too?

Comment: @AkashKC - I added the Get for it.

Comment: Try with changing your action to `public ActionResult UsageReport([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,string DateStart)`

Comment: @AkashKC - I get the same error at the same place.

Comment: @Andarta try commenting out the filters in the grid and see if it hits the read method.

Comment: @BillRuhl - Thanks, but that made no difference, either.  FYI, I added a link to a video of what walking through it looks like (where the error pops up).  Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So although I admittedly don't fully understand why this wasn't working, I got around it by reworking how the grid gets its data.  Instead of setting the grid's DataSource properties and using a Read function, I specify the model for the grid like so:
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.LoginHistories)
And I added "LoginHistories" as a property of the model my view is using.  So in the Get function, I just set that property similar to what the Read function was doing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my `MODEL` had 2 properties with similar name:

```
public int? corporateId { get; set; }
public int? CorporateId { get; set; }
```

One was CamelCase, and other wasn't.

Solution was simply to remove one or change the name of one of them:

```
//public int? corporateId { get; set; }
public int? corporate_id { get; set; }
public int? CorporateId { get; set; }
```